# IEEE Xplore no bookmark

Tags: citing, ieeetran, bookmarks

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

`IEEE Xplore` paper asks to remove bookmarks, I have no idea why even after I added:

```
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks={false}}{hyperref}
```

Still it puts shows the links and bookmarks in the citation part of the pdf. A help would be greatly appreciated.

```
% *** MISC UTILITY PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{ifpdf}
% Heiko Oberdiek's ifpdf.sty is very useful if you need conditional
% compilation based on whether the output is pdf or dvi.
% usage:
% \ifpdf
%   % pdf code
% \else
%   % dvi code
% \fi
% The latest version of ifpdf.sty can be obtained from:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/
% Also, note that IEEEtran.cls V1.7 and later provides a builtin
% \ifCLASSINFOpdf conditional that works the same way.
% When switching from latex to pdflatex and vice-versa, the compiler may
% have to be run twice to clear warning/error messages.





\else
\fi





% *** PDF, URL AND HYPERLINK PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{url}
% url.sty was written by Donald Arseneau. It provides better support for
% handling and breaking URLs. url.sty is already installed on most LaTeX
% systems. The latest version can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/misc/
% Read the url.sty source comments for usage information. Basically,
% \url{my_url_here}.

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks={false}}{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It should be fine now.

Comment: @MajicJohnson: Your document is still only a fragment

Answer (score 3):

This (minimal) document produces no bookmarks. Saying `bookmarks=true` or removing the statement `bookmarks=false` will enable them (perhaps it's necessary to click on the bookmarks panel of the viewer to see them in this case)

Some remarks, unconnected to the underlying problem

- The `\else ...\fi` pair is not matched  -- will lead to a compilation error then
- `\PassOptionsToPackage` is probably not necessary in this case.
- `hyperref` should be the last package to be included in almost any case (unless `cleveref` is used too)

---

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}


\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}



\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{first}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]