# How to get bookmarks shown in ICML 2022 style

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

When I use the example file

[icml2022.zip](https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2022/Styles/icml2022.zip) from https://icml.cc/Conferences/2022/StyleAuthorInstructions,

there are no bookmarks shown in any pdf reader. Typically most pdf reader show a table of content as bookmarks left to the pdf, when `hyperref` is loaded (see [How do I create bookmarks with pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346412/how-do-i-create-bookmarks-with-pdflatex)).

How can I change the code to show the bookmarks? Or which packages are in conflict with the bookmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\usepackage{icml2022}`
has been loaded after
`\usepackage{hyperref}`, but as mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244889/128042:

> `hyperref` should be the last package to be included in almost any case (unless `cleveref` is used too)

I deleted `\usepackage{hyperref}` and added it directly in the line after `\usepackage{icml2022}` and now the bookmarks are shown correctly :)

Is there any disadvantage of loading the packages in the correct order? Do you think ICML loads the packages on purpose in the wrong order? So far it seems to me that changing the order of the packages into the correct order only brought advantages over the code suggested by ICML 2022.

Comment: well by exchanging the order you are disabling the section definitions of the journal style.

Comment: Which section definitions? Can you give an example for LaTeX code of section definitions or can you explain how this affects the resulting pdf? Is there a possibility to make both work at the same time? Section definitions and bookmarks?

Comment: You are changing a definition of the package by changing the order. And at least one effect on the pdf is obvious as it is the reason you are changing the order. If you create the pdf for a submission then ask the journal if it matters for them.